# shell script mv is throwing unhelpful error "No such file or directory" even though i see it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mv

I need to use a shell script to move all files in a directory into another directory.  I manually did this without a problem and now scripting it is giving me an error on the `mv` command.

Inside the directory I want to move files out of are 2 directories, php and php.tmp.  The error I get is `cd: /path/to/working/directory/php: No such file or directory`.  I'm confused because it is there to begin with and listed when I ls the working directory.

The error I get is here:

```
ls $PWD #ensure the files are there
mv $PWD/* /company/home/directory
ls /company/home/directory #ensure the files are moved
```

When I use `ls $PWD` I see the directories I want to move but the error afterward says it doesn't exist.  Then when I ssh to the machine this is running on I see the files were moved correctly.

If it matters the directory I am moving files from is owned by a different user but the shell is executing as root.

I don't understand why I would get this error so, any help would be great.

Comment: What happens if you just do `mv $PWD/php /company/home/directory` ?

Comment: You mentioned ssh'ing to the machine this is running on -- is this script being run remotely or something like that, and if so how?

Comment: How do you lauch your script?

Comment: The weirdest part is that you get an error from `cd` even though your posted script has no `cd`statement.

Comment: @jdamian  This is a gitlab runner so, a gitlab server is dumping the repo onto the runner (the machine i ssh to) and the script lives in the repo which is triggered as part of the gitlab server build script.

Comment: @thatotherguy i don't understand that either.  I commented out all the other logic in the script and the snippet i posted always recreates the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `/` after the path to specify you want to move the file, not rename the directory.

You should try this:

```
mv $PWD/\*  /home/user/directory/
```

Comment: This got rid of the error messages but the mv still fails

Answer (score 0):

Are your variables properly quoted?  You could try :

```
ls "$PWD" #ensure the files are there
mv "$PWD"/* "/company/home/directory"
ls "/company/home/directory" #ensure the files are moved
```

If any of your file or directory names contains characters such as spaces or tabs, your "mv" command may not be seeing the argument list you think it is seeing.

Comment: If quoting is the issue, `ls` should have the same problem as `mv`.

Comment: The quoting shouldn't matter unless outputting that right?  Anyways, I tried quoting the variable but no luck.

Comment: Quoting is always important.  Suppose you have a directory named "/my directory" (with a space).  trying "mv somefile /my directory" will not work.  Even if this has nothing to do with your current problem, you should always quote variables containing filenames when expanding them.  The "ls" command has no globbing, the "mv" does, so nothing says both should have the same issue.